# Swift Get value from Array to Plist

Tags: swift, ios8, string-conversion

I would like to extract a value from an array loaded from plist

```
var buttonPointReload = data!["\(strFromPass)"] as? Dictionary<String, String>
    if var dict = buttonPointReload {
           for (one, two) in dict {
              println(dict)   //  I  have [Button 1: [-200, -90]]
              println(one)    // I  have Button 1
              println(two)    // I  have [-200, -90]
              println("\(one[0])")

    }}
```

I save my Array in this mode

```
        var arrPosition : [String] = []
        var x: Int = ("\(line)").toInt()!
        var y: Int = ("\(column)").toInt()!

        arrPosition = ["\(x)"]
        arrPosition.append("\(y)")
        dict["Button \(index)"] = "\(arrPosition)"
        data?.setValue(dict, forKey: "\(strFromPass)")
        data?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

I am trying in this way but I get

```
Int doesn't have member named 'substring'
```

how can I get the value -200 ?

Comment: If your dictionary has the type `Dictionary<String, String>` then the values are *strings* and `two` is the *string* `"[-200, -90]"`. So the question is: Why did you store the coordinates as a string and not as an array of two numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **CGPointFromString** to convert a **String**

```
"[-200, -90]"
```

into a **CGPoint** struct.

Once you have a **CGPoint** you can easily access the **x** and **y** values.

You can paste this code inside your **FOR** loop.

```
let point : CGPoint = CGPointFromString(two)
println("x: \(point.x) and y: \(point.y)") // "x: -200.0 and y: -90.0"
```

Just note the CGPoint stores the x and y into **Float**(s), not **Int**(s).